# Understand the result of PartialOrd Rust

Tags: rust

I have the following piece of code:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use core::cmp::{Ord, Ordering};

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, Debug)]
struct Sample(i32, Vec<i32>);

impl PartialOrd for Sample {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if self.0 < other.0 {
            return Some(Ordering::Less);
        }
        return Some(Ordering::Greater);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut max_heap: BinaryHeap<Sample> = BinaryHeap::new();
    max_heap.push(Sample(3, vec![1,2]));
    for i in max_heap.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
    println!();

    max_heap.push(Sample(7, vec![2,3]));
    for i in max_heap.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
    println!();

    max_heap.push(Sample(5, vec![1,6]));
    for i in max_heap.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=91bb23238740d6bb2b54e83c7ff5d43c)

where I am trying to implement the comparator on the first value of the struct (`Sample`).

It gives the following output:

```
Sample(3, [1, 2])

Sample(7, [2, 3])
Sample(3, [1, 2])

Sample(7, [2, 3])
Sample(3, [1, 2])
Sample(5, [1, 6])
```

Perhaps it is a dumb question/ something obvious - but does it not order by the first field of the struct in descending order? I was expecting the output (ignoring the vector) to be `7, 5, 3` but it is `7, 3, 5`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior.

`BinaryHeap::iter` explicitly states in [its documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html#method.iter):

> Returns an iterator visiting all values in the underlying vector, in arbitrary order.

The reason to this, according to [this tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59278), is that this iterator was implemented as reversible, but it's impossible to iterate through the ordered iterator over binary heap from the back: we know only the largest element, but not the smallest one.

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryHeap`'s `iter` function returns an iterator visiting all values in **arbitary** order. So, that explains why the values yielded from the iterator are not sorted.

Instead, you can call the `into_sorted_vec` function to get a vector in sorted order like below.

```
let v = max_heap.into_sorted_vec();
for i in v.iter() {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

Also, you can also call the 'pop' function to get the greatest item from the binary heap one by one.

```
while let Some(i) = max_heap.pop() {
    println!("{:?}", i);
}
```

Please note that both `into_sorted_vec` and `pop` consume the original heap. If you just need to know the greatest item without removing it from the heap, you can use the `peek` function.